# Using user-defined ADD_EXECUTABLE in CMake with KDevelop 4

Tags: macros, cmake, kdevelop

We have defined our own ADD_EXECUTABLE macro (TDS_ADD_EXECUTABLE) for our cmake files which handles some nice internal functionality for us.

The problem is, when I load up our project in KDevelop 4 (linux) while it finds and builds our entire system, it does not add any of the executables to the Project Targets list for configuring the launches. This makes it a real management nightmare to do any work in KDevelop since we have to manually add all of our executables.

Is there a way to tell KDevelop our TDS_ADD_EXECUTABLE performs an ADD_EXECUTABLE... or something like this? I was actually surprised it was unable to fathom this on it's own since it's all scripted.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand this correctly - `TDS_ADD_EXECUTABLE` is just a macro around `ADD_EXECUTABLE`? If so, KDevelop should figure that out automagically. Post a small testcase to the correct place: http://bugs.kde.org